# Listbox in tkinter graps focus on first row when show in a grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a widget for searching in a list of objects. For this I create a frame containing a Entry and a ListBox (with a horizontal and vertical scrollbar) using a grid. The idea is to show in the ListBpx the suggestions that match the text in the Entry, updating the list if the text in the Entry is changed. Once a suggestion in the ListBox is selected the entry is updated with the suggestion and the ListBox disappears. If new text in the Entry is typed de the ListBox appears again. I use the grid and grid_remove methods to show/hide the ListBox and the scrollbars.
The problem Is with focus on the Entry. If you run the code below and

- Click on the Entry and  type in some text the Listbox appears and is filtered by the text as should be.
- Click on one of the suggestions in the Listbox the textbox is updated as should be.
- Click on the Entry and type in one character, the focus is set on the first row of the listbox and you can not type in anymore in the Entry, unless you click on the Entry again, causing the focus to be set on the Entry and then everything works as should be.

How can I avoid that the ListBox get the focus and the Entry loses focus. I tried the methods focus() and focus_set() on the entry or the option setfocus=0 on the Listbox to avoid this but nothing seems to work.

Any help is really appreciated.

Marc

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class SearchEntryBase(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, toStr = str, rows = [], *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._selected = None
        self.toStr = toStr
        self._rows = rows
        visible_rows = []
        entry_content = StringVar()
        entry = ttk.Entry(self,textvariable=entry_content)

        listbox = Listbox(self,selectmode=SINGLE)
        hscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=listbox.xview)
        vscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=listbox.yview)
        listbox.configure(xscroll = hscroll.set)
        listbox.configure(yscroll = vscroll.set)
        # Place in a grid
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky= (W, E))
        listbox.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=(N, S, E, W))
        hscroll.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=(E, W))
        vscroll.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=[N, S])
        # By default hide the frame
        listbox.grid_remove()
        vscroll.grid_remove()
        hscroll.grid_remove()
        # Called when a entry in the listbox is selected
        def selector(event):
            listbox.grid_remove()
            vscroll.grid_remove()
            hscroll.grid_remove()
            s = listbox.curselection()
            if s:
                i=s[0]
                entry_content.set(listbox.get(i))
                self._selected = visible_rows[i]
            listbox.select_clear(0,END)
            listbox.focus_set()

        listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',selector)
        # Specify the entry validator
        def updator(event):
            value=entry_content.get()
            visible_rows.clear()
            listbox.delete(0,END)
            for row in self._rows:
                str = self.toStr(row)
                if value == str:
                    self._selected = row
                else:
                    self._selected = None
                if value in str:
                    visible_rows.append(row)
                    listbox.insert(END,str)
            if not(visible_rows):
                for row in self._rows:
                    visible_rows.append(row)
                    listbox.insert(END,self.toStr(row))
            listbox.grid()
            vscroll.grid()
            hscroll.grid()
            return True
            # Show the list box if we have typed in somthing
        entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',updator)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

rows=['Jan','Piet','Joris','Corneel','AAA','BBB','ABC']

se=SearchEntryBase(root,rows=rows)
se.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='new')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `entry.focus_force()` at the end of `updator()` (before `return True`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it out but it does not solve the problem, If it makes any difference I run the program on Linux maybe the behavior is different in Mac Os or Windows.